# Is it possible to tunnel Azure SQL over http?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have an issue where I need to debug my application locally while on VPN to access corporate API's. The VPN client (also corporate) routes all traffic through the VPN and does not allow port 1433, which in turn prevents me from accessing my Azure Database.

I can't work around the VPN restrictions, so I was wondering if there is another way to access the database. I have been working with On-premises data gateway before, but only to access local databases from the cloud, not the other way around.

Comment: Are you sure you can't add a route to your client to route out of your normal IP endpoint?  Otherwise, can you create a VM jumpbox in Azure and RDP into that over your VPN?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not an expert on network and there seams to be many ports to setup. If you've ever done it, I'd be eager to see which commands you're running. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add routes for Azure IoT hub and now it works:

```bash
route add 40.68.37.158 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1;
route add 104.40.168.105 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1;
route add 52.236.184.163 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1;
route add 104.42.195.92 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1;
```